# if today date is my custom date then show div

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to make an formular where when user select if he want to signup at that event before 01.08.2019 he needs to pay 350$ if he signup after 01.08.2019 that price change to 450$, how i can to this with jquery, or php? i need to put these prices in some fields hidden.
(if today date is before 01.08.2019 then price will be 350$ and if is after that date price will be 450$)

```
<div class="group">
   <input type="checkbox"> Sign up
   <input type="hidden" id='price' value=''>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean ....

Comment: i think is simple but i cant explain, if user sign-up before 01.08.2019 the price will be 350$ if the user sign up after 01.08.2019 like 02.08.2019 the price will be 450$ is some javascript to detect today date and if is after 01.08.2019 some javascript will echo in that hidden input 450$.

Comment: Check my solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var end_date = new Date("2018-08-01"); // 01 August 2018
        price = 350;
        if (currentDate > end_date) {
            price = 450;
        }
        $("#price").val(price);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What is default?

Comment: same question, i think is a variable.

Comment: it is a variable, forgot to change it to price

Comment: var currentDate = new Date(); this will give the IST format of date.. we will not be able to compare.

Comment: youre right, thanks for correcting

Comment: So it`s can be compared?

Comment: what needs to be compared?

Comment: the current date and end date (ex: 20.02.2019 today and end date 01.08.2019 because if it is 02.08.2019 the price will change )

Comment: yes it will change the price if today date (currentDate) is beyond the end_date

Comment: how i can test this? i need to change date from my computer?

Comment: you can manipulate `currentDate` variable to something like this `var currentDate = new Date("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using simple Javascript.

Get todays date and compare it with the `end_date`.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();
currentDate = currentDate.getDate() + '-' + currentDate.getMonth() + '-' + currentDate.getFullYear()
var end_date = "2018-08-01"; // 01 August 2018
price = 350;
if (currentDate !== end_date) {
    price = 450;
}

document.getElementById('price').value = price;
        
console.log(document.getElementById('price'))
```

```html
<div class="group">
   <input type="checkbox"> Sign up
   <input type="hidden" id='price' value=''>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want to do with jquery use $('#price').val(price).